# Postgresql delete taking lots of CPU and time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, performance, postgresql-performance

I have the following SQL Query for deleting rows from my table. The query takes a long time and puts a high load on my server.

```
delete from message_log where from_id = ? OR to_id = ?
```

My table Schema

```
-- Table: message_log

CREATE TABLE message_log
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  message text,
  from_id character varying(500),
  to_id character varying(500),
  match_id character varying(500),
  unix_timestamp bigint,
  own_account boolean,
  reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT message_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT message_log_message_from_id_to_id_match_id_unix_timestamp_key UNIQUE (message, from_id, to_id, match_id, unix_timestamp)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE message_log
  OWNER TO t;


CREATE INDEX delete_index
  ON message_log
  USING btree
  (from_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default", to_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");


CREATE INDEX message_log_from_id_to_id_unix_timestamp_idx
  ON message_log
  USING btree
  (from_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default", to_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default", unix_timestamp);

CREATE INDEX message_log_match_id_unix_timestamp_idx
  ON message_log
  USING btree
  (match_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default", unix_timestamp);
```

I already have an index on from_id and to_id. Is there anything I can do to speed the delete process up? I am running Postgres 9.1

EDIT

I tried the explain query

```
EXPLAIN delete from message_log where from_id = '55fc5c2c2a0defed5b643d40' OR to_id = '55fc5c2c2a0defed5b643d40'
```

Three rows are returned

```
1. "Delete on message_log  (cost=0.00..89443.96 rows=96 width=6)"
2. "  ->  Seq Scan on message_log  (cost=0.00..89443.96 rows=96 width=6)"
3. "        Filter: (((from_id)::text = '55fc5c2c2a0defed5b643d40'::text) OR ((to_id)::text = '55fc5c2c2a0defed5b643d40'::text))"
```

Comment: Are you using a single transaction or multiple deletes? Have you tried doing the `DELETE` with two queries instead of one, since the `WHERE` clause is an `OR` instead of an `AND`?

Comment: @Kassandry my delete query would delete multiple rows once it is executed. Is there nothing else I can do besides multiple deletes?

Comment: Would upgrading the server make a big difference? I'm running it on a Linode 2GB right now.

Comment: I don't think it's using the index for all operations. A simple `EXPLAIN` will help a lot

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have edited my question, showing the results of EXPLAIN. As you said I don't think the index is being used. Am I correct?

Comment: Are they deleted rows the target of foreign key constraints from other tables with `on delete cascade`?

Comment: Also, your `delete_index` isn't actually that useful for the delete, because the column conditions are ORed not ANDed. In this case you're better off with two independent indexes that PostgreSQL can combine with a bitmap index scan. Or, as @Kassandry suggests, using two queries. Also, if 9.1 supports it (I don't remember) use `column < 'deadbeef' COLLATE "C"` to speed up the text comparison. (Those fields should by bytea, not varchar, but eh)

Comment: @CraigRinger I added two separate indexes and I think that fixed the issue.